# Fmod listener position

Tags: iphone, fmod

Is it possible to have several sounds on different places in a 3D sound world in Fmod? I would like to plot up all the sounds in this 3D world and move around the player.

I am developing for iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code allowed me to place several sounds that were made into events in Fmod Designer into a 3D world of Fmod:

```
FMOD_RESULT     result = FMOD_OK;
FMOD_VECTOR     listenerpos = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
FMOD_VECTOR     eventpos        = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
FMOD_VECTOR     eventpos2        = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

float DISTANCEFACTOR          = 2.0f;
```

Event 1 is one of the sounds I want to place in my 3D world:

```
result = group->getEvent("Event 1", FMOD_EVENT_DEFAULT, &event1);
ERRCHECK(result);
```

Event 2 is the other event I want to place in the same sounds landscape:

```
result = group->getEvent("Event 2", FMOD_EVENT_DEFAULT, &event2);
ERRCHECK(result);
```

I place the listener position in the middle of this world:

```
listenerpos.x = 0;
listenerpos.y = 0;
listenerpos.z = 0;

result = eventSystem->set3DListenerAttributes(0, &listenerpos,NULL,NULL,NULL);
ERRCHECK(result);
```

I set the position of one of the events to an object I move around on the iPhone screen:

```
eventpos.x = xPos;
eventpos.z = yPos;
result = event1->set3DAttributes(&eventpos,&vel);
ERRCHECK(result);
```

I set the other event to another position:

```
eventpos2.x = xPos2;
eventpos2.y = yPos2;

result = event2->set3DAttributes(&eventpos2,&vel);
ERRCHECK(result);
```

The entire event system and 3D world is updated with these positions:

```
result = eventSystem->update();
ERRCHECK(result);
```

I trigger the 2 events and hear how they move around the listener:

```
result = event1->start();
ERRCHECK(result);

result = event2->start();
ERRCHECK(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To place a channel or event in a 3D location use either Channel::set3DAttributes or Event::set3DAttributes, these functions take a 3D world position and a direction vector.

If you want to "walk" around the 3D world, you need to adjust the listener position with either System::set3DListenerAttributes or EventSystem::set3DListenerAttributes (depending on if you are using FMOD low level API or FMOD Event System API. These functions take a position vector, velocity vector, forward vector and up vector.

I recommend referring to the 3D example that ships with FMOD and checking fmodex.chm for more details about the above functions.

Comment: I used one of the examples from Fmod but it is not clear if I can position more than one sound.

Comment: Yes, you can position any number of sounds. Each FMOD::Channel represents a playing instance of an FMOD::Sound, you can play the same sound multiple times to receive multiple channels, each can be positioned.